# Windows 8 product key from Dreamspark does not work

Tags: windows, product-key, dreamspark

I recently downloaded Windows 8 Professional N 32/64 and got a product key from Dreamspark.
However when I try to install Windows 8, it asks me for a product key. I enter it and it fails:

> The present key you have entered will not work with this edition of Windows. Try another key.

I checked the product key, and even copy pasted it. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you download Windows 8 Pro N 32/64 from dreamspark as well?

Comment: Musa, Yes I did, I downloaded it this morning from Dreamspark shop. @Ofiris: I already checked the product key many times in my shopping cart, I copy/pasted it. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Check out your shopping cart, you would be able to see the correct CD-KEY for your downloaded product.

If you have more than one download, maybe you got confused.

Comment: Hi Oliveira. Please register your Stack Overflow account, then come back here and log in with the same details here. This way you can edit your question, add comments, et cetera.

Comment: Sorry slhck, it seems to be okay now, isnt it ?

Comment: Copy/Paste won't help, It's not that you're entering the key wrong, it's that you're entering the wrong key. :)  For example: the non-"N" keys won't work with the "N" media.

Comment: Doublecheck that the key you're using is from the same "purchase" as the download.  If it still doesn't work, you can try the Dreamspark help request system, although as this goes to your university/school/college/whatever rather than directly to MS you might not get a response until the holidays are over.  You could also try phoning MS, activation support is free of charge IIRC.

Comment: Do you have the right architecture? My understanding is that a product key is for 32 bit or 64 bit versions of Windows. So while your installation media has both, the key's only good for one of them.

Comment: A MVP on Microsoft Answers website said i should try to download again the file because the .ISO is may be corrupted... If it doesn't solve the problem, i will contact Dreamspark...

Comment: @ta.speot.is : my current OS is Win7 x64 and i download the x64 Win8 version. But i try the x86 Win8 version anyway and it doesn't work as expected. So the key is good for the x64 version...

Comment: @Ofiris : i currently downloaded one only product on Dreamspark website, i'm sure that the given key is for the Windows 8 Professional N 32/64 :s

Comment: I have just finish to download the file again and it still does not work... I don't think the file is corrupted.

Comment: I had the same problem with Czech Windows 8 N x64 version. I solved it by downloading English non-N (installation without any problems) and installing Czech language pack. So far everything is translated and works

Answer (score 1):

Call 1-877-MY-MS-STORE (1-877-696-7786) for US/CA support, or UK support at 0844 800 2400. Oddly enough, the Microsoft Store is the support provider for DreamSpark purchases.